# Redis StackExchange SortedSetAddAsync with expiry in one call

Tags: c#, stackexchange.redis

I am trying to add a SortedSet entry with expiry on the key. Is there any better way than 2 calls? 
This is what I am currently using:

```
    private IDatabase GetDataBase()
    {
        return this.GetLeastBusyMultiplexer().GetDatabase();
    }

    private ConnectionMultiplexer GetLeastBusyMultiplexer()
    {
        var leastBusyMultiplexer = this.Multiplexers.Aggregate((min, next) =>
        {
            if (min == null || next.Value.GetCounters().TotalOutstanding < min.Value.GetCounters().TotalOutstanding)
            {
                return next;
            }

            return min;
        });

        return leastBusyMultiplexer.Value;
    }`
```

And adding to the database is here:

```
 var RedisDatabase = GetDataBase();
 RedisDatabase.SortedSetAddAsync(key, sortedSetEntry,whenNotExists)).ConfigureAwait(false);
 RedisDatabase.KeyExpireAsync(key, ttlValue).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're worrying about race condition, try [transaction or lua script](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis/blob/master/docs/Transactions.md).

Comment: thanks Leisen! I was wondering if there is a way to send just one request to the server itself :)

Comment: will give it a bit more time and if not possible will mark your answer as correct :)

Comment: Transaction include [multiple redis commands](https://redis.io/topics/transactions).Lua script will send only one [EVAL command](https://redis.io/commands/eval).